# Handling response from GraphQL API with axios

Tags: typescript, axios, graphql

I can successfully make the post request I want to like this:

```
async function fn(): Promise<MediaListCollection> {
  let result = {} as MediaListCollection;

  await axios
    .post<MediaListCollection>(
      "https://graphql.anilist.co/",
      {
        query: USER_LIST_CURRENT,
        variables: {
          userId: 831347,
          status: MediaListStatus.Current,
          type: MediaType.Anime,
        },
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => (result = response.data))
    .catch((err) => {
      throw {
        error: err,
      };
    });

  return result;
}

fn()
  .then((data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
  .catch((err) => console.log(JSON.stringify(err)));
```

But the output ends up being:

```
{"data":{"MediaListCollection":{"lists":[{"name":"Watching","entries":[{"id":158643971,"mediaId":5081,"status":"CURRENT","score":0,"progress":10,"repeat":0,"media":{"title":{"userPreferred":"Bakemonogatari"},"coverImage":{"extraLarge":"https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx5081-YpAE43HLQKqz.png"},"format":"TV","status":"FINISHED","episodes":15,"averageScore":83,"isAdult":false,"genres":["Comedy","Drama","Mystery","Psychological","Romance","Supernatural"],"bannerImage":"https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/banner/n5081-0Zcn5GOFYHMc.jpg","startDate":{"year":2009,"month":7,"day":3}}}]}]}}}
```

And so I try to access the entry list 0:

```
fn()
  .then((data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data.lists![0])))
  .catch((err) => console.log(JSON.stringify(err)));
```

I get

```
{}
```

I see that the response has a bigger object, "data", is there any way to overcome this? I don't think I need to go over every type and add it, or do I?

Comment: data .. Media... lists[0]

Comment: That's not a property of the [type](https://imgur.com/a/WuaG2u4) I've defined

Comment: typing problem ... graphql by default returns data wrapped in `data` because response.data can contain `errors` (not cacheable network errors) and query/mutation name level ... you can remove them to return an array only by `.then((response) => (result = response.data.data.MediaListCollection))`

Comment: Yup, I thought there could be some workaround, and I kind of got one but not the way I wanted it, I'm gonna post it.

Comment: if you're typing your `fn` result as `Promise<MediaListCollection>` then you can't just return entire graphql response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As xadm says,

> graphql by default returns data wrapped in data (...)

The closest approach we can get keeping it hard typed would be:

```
async function fetch<T>(query: string, variables: Object): Promise<T> {
  return await axios
    .post(
      "https://graphql.anilist.co/",
      {
        query,
        variables,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => response.data.data)
    .catch((err) => {
      throw {
        error: err,
      };
    });
}
```

Calling fetch:

```
fetch<MediaListCollection>(USER_LIST_CURRENT, {
  userId: 831347,
  status: MediaListStatus.Current,
  type: MediaType.Anime,
})
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```